# Plesk 11 - Custom Error Documents, URL fails with "Wrong URL format"

Tags: windows, iis, http-status-code-404, custom-errors

I am setting up a new Plesk account and want to add a custom error document, 404, specifying a URL to a PHP file.

In another account, which uses an earlier version of Plesk (v10, if not mistaken), the following method works, just not in Plesk 11.

1. Go to Websites & Domains | Virtual Directories
2. [Manage] for domain
3. Select 'Error Documents' tab
4. Click on All | click on 404
5. Select Url as the Type
6. Type in '/Index.php' as the Location
7. List item

Note, file is in root of the selected domain.

Received error:

```
Error: Wrong URL format. Please enter an absolute URL within the virtual host (site).
Location is highlighted
```

In previous versions of Plesk, or at least in the other account, specifying "/Index.php" worked.

If I were using ASP.Net, I could probably modify the `web.config` file, however I am using PHP here, not ASP.Net.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is your **operating system** (Windows or Linux) ?

Comment: Windows, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: why don't you contact the [Parallels Plesk Support](http://www.parallels.com/de/store/support/plesk/) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like behaviour was changed. 
What about add permanent redirect in not_found.html file or use absolute URL to index.php?

Comment: I was able to add in an absolute path in the form, http://www.<domain name here>/Index.php, however I have a couple of URLs that use the same domain name and I was hoping to keep a relative path. using the http://www.domain1.com/Index.php will redirect users from http://www.domain2.com. I thought of this answer yesterday, but did not try it. I added that in for now.